Error on app launching using eas build in monorepo
I'm struggling a lot to figure out why do my application fails on iOS.
I have a monorepo with the following architecture:
- apps/
  - app1/
    - package.json
    - eas.json
    - src/
    - ...
  - app2/
    - ...
- packages/
- package.json

I run eas build --platform ios --local within apps/app1 such as mentioned on Expo ressources. This creates properly the build. I do manage to install it into the emulator and launch the app. However, I immediately get multiple errors that seem to be relative to imports from the package.json from the root level. What am I doing wrong?
I got multiple errors:

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.
Error: Cannot find native module 'ExponentAV', js engine: hermes
Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoSecureStore', js engine: hermes
Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null
Error: [Reanimated] Native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized.

Content of the the package.json at the root level:
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.11",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.5",
    "expo-constants": "^16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.15",
    "expo-font": "^12.0.6",
    "expo-linking": "^6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "^3.5.15",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3",
    "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.7"
  }
}


Content of app#1/package.json
{
  "name": "solfy-mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.18",
    "@myapp/package1": "*",
    "@myapp/package2": "*",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "expo-updates": "^0.25.16",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "wavefile": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Remark: the app works properly when using Expo Go using the following command:
npm run start --workspace app1

Could yo help, I do not managed to understand what's going on. I probably miss something in the monorepo confguration using expo/router or monorepo root dependencies, or something like that?

I tried to edit packages.json files, eas.json, metro and rebuild but I did not managed to figure out where is the misconfiguration exactly.
Thanks for your help!
